# replace matching words python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this codition:

```
if "Exit" in name:
   replace_name = name.replace("Exit","`Exit`")
   name = replace_name
```

and it should replace Exit with 'Exit' but if I have another word like exited, it also replaces it 'Exit'. I only want it to replace the exact one "Exit" not exited. what is the best way to overcome this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: what is name exactly? You could try replacing the if statement with: if name == 'Exit':

Comment: You can try 'name.replace("Exit", "'Exit'", 1)' to replace only one time.

Comment: thanks alot. I don't know why i didn't think of that :).

Comment: If you just mean: `if name=="Exit": name="\`Exit\`"` that is not the question you asked, and it is not really about replacing words.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) with word boundary (`\b`) characters. Also, no need for the `if` check; if the word is not in the string, then nothing is replaced.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "he exited through the exit"
>>> re.sub(r"\bexit\b", "'exit'", s)
"he exited through the 'exit'"
```

You could also use flags to make the match case insensitive, or use a callback function for determining the replacement

```
>>> s = "he exited through the Exit"
>>> re.sub(r"\b(exit)\b", lambda m: "'%s'"%m.group(1).upper(), s, flags=re.I)
"he exited through the 'EXIT'"
```

Comment: OP wants backticks in the replacement

Comment: Maybe this should use case insensitive matching, since the OP is actually asking about "Exit", not "exit".

Comment: @PM2Ring Replacing ' with ` is left as an exercise to the reader. They were escaped in the output, so I used`'` instead so the replacement is clearer.

Comment: Fair enough, Tobias.

Comment: Could I suggest the slightly less complicated-looking `re.sub(r'\b(exit)\b', r"'\1'", s, flags=re.I)`

Answer (score 0):

Use `re` for this.

```
import re
replaced_name=re.sub(r"\bExit\b","`Exit`",name)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Input:**

```
name = ['dr.doom','spiderman',"Exit", 'exited']

if "Exit" in name:
    index = name.index("Exit")
    name.pop(index)
    name.insert(index, "'Exit'")

print(name)
```

**Output:**

```
['dr.doom', 'spinderman', "'Exit'", 'exited']
```

Answer (score -1):

I should've wrote it this way:

```
if name == "Exit":
   replace_name = name.replace("Exit","`Exit`")
   name = replace_name
```

Comment: If you can guarantee that `name` is a single word, and you want this to be case-sensitive, why even bother doing a replace operation? Just do `if name == "Exit":` `name = "\`Exit\`"`